# What is reverse chanting?

Tags: rituals, shiva, prayer

Someone told a priest that he wants to pray in *reverse* and the priest told him this:

> You are praying like *Om Namah Shivay* currently. So you need to pray now *Shivay Namah Om*.

So my question is what is *reverse* chanting and what does it signify?

Comment: yeah I heard the same reverse chant by many people. I think you mean "chant" but not "worship".. :)

Comment: Reverse worship sounds like a taunt. Like reverse cleaning would be smearing :-)

Comment: i don't know about it @MKaama you may mean something but i want to understand it

Comment: @MKaama check this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gEx3ldOUBs

Comment: at least by semantics both, 'Om namah shivaya' and 'Shivaya namah om' are same.

Comment: Also, changing the word order in Sanskrit does not reverse the phrase, meaning stays the same, because word relationships are indicated by inflection. Word order gets customarily changed in Sanskrit poetry.

Comment: @MKaama, you might put that as an answer.. I too think the same. Check my comment. But I don't know if there is any ritualistic significance to it.

Comment: Sanskrit sentence meaning remains same even if we are changing its order. 
http://forum.aryanways.in/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1501

Comment: Is the question about whether Sanskrita meaning changes with word other or not. Or is the question about- what is the result and purpose of chanting a mantra or Shloka in reverse order of words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing the word order in Sanskrit does not reverse the phrase meaning. Meaning stays the same, because word relationships are indicated by inflection.

Word order gets customarily changed in Sanskrit poetry. Example:

> namas te gaura vānī šrī mūrtaye dīna tārine 
>   rūpānuga viruddhāpasiddhānta dhvānta hārine

and

> gaurāvirbhāva bhūmes tvam nirdeštā saj jana priyah 
>   vaišnava sārvabhaumah šrī jagannāthāya te namah

in both verses "*namah te*" and "*te namah*" mean the same thing, "*I bow down before you*".

Comment: Thats a beauty of Sanskrit.

Comment: Here is the example of order
http://forum.aryanways.in/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1501

Answer (score 3):

Om Namah shivaya indicates positive energy. If any body chants the reverse that means "**Yavashih Mana Mo**" its a negative energy. Generally used in voodoo or Black magic. For any query watch Vikramaditya YouTube channel on black magic.

Comment: Can you provide link of that video? If possible, can you mention any scripture where this is mentioned.